# f2py.exe is somewhere, but the directory isn't on path

Tags: python, numpy, pip, path

I'm using pip to install some stuff such as numpy and pandas. When I install numpy, it tells me that the directories aren't on path. When I try to import these things, I get an error messages saying those modules don't exist. Does this path have something to do with the modules not working? and how do I fix this? I work on windows 10 using python 3.9

```
 WARNING: The script f2py.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\denpi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Comment: when using pycharm, i can find the numpy library, but when importing it says i dont have the multiarray function,.which I was also able to find in in the numpy file. I don't understand what's goin on

Answer (score 8):

On Windows 10:

Click start, search for "environment variables".

or

Use windows + R key to run command, run the following "sysdm.cpl"
then (if used win+R key): go to advanced tab, theres a box (system variables)

Then in system variables search for "Path",
click on it, click "Edit". A new window pops up. Click "New" and paste in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Scripts".

If the box does not have a variable named "path" click New to create one, set the name to "Path", and the value to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Scripts".