# I downloaded a python library, and it still says that the library cannot be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-venv

I am using Windows 11, Visual Studio Code, Python version 3.11.2 and I am trying to download the matplotlib. I was following the tutorial of this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial
It was helpful for the most part, but then when I downloaded the library, it said:
" warning: the script f2py.exe is installed in 'c:\python\python37\scripts' which is not on path. "
And when I try download it again, it says that the parts are still there, but when I see the "Problems" tab, it says: " Import "matplotlib.pyplot" could not be resolved from source "
I have no clue on how to fix this issue and I can't seem to find anyone else with the same problem.

I did find this thing about opening "environment variables", but nothing changed and it wasn't very helpful. [f2py.exe is somewhere, but the directory isn't on path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69547919/f2py-exe-is-somewhere-but-the-directory-isnt-on-path)

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure pip and python to be using the same version. If pip installs to the Python 3.7 directory, then it won't be available in Python 3.11.

Comment: how can you tell what version of pip you are using?

Comment: @SantiagoRivas You can use `pip --version`

Comment: For some reason I was able to download the library without pip, so it says it doesn't have pip installed